# can i Import tools and features from visual studio 2017 to 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

Is there any way i can import VS 2017 tools and features to VS 2019?

I just find it annoying if I have to re-download everything for Vs 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/473382/vs-2019-preview-4-doesnt-import-settings-from-vs-2.html

> The warnings you saw were by design, since VS doesn't support (and has
>   never supported) migrating those particular settings between major
>   versions. The error regarding the "Startup" setting is harmless and
>   you can ignore it.

Because the underlying code changes between major VS versions, it is not possible to simply export content from one version and import it to another. Plugin authors must change their code for each version of Visual Studio they support, requiring fresh downloads of the "same" plugins for each version you run.